# Program to solve a system of linear equations in C++

Tags: c++

I am testing this code for solving linear systems with this simple 2-equation system (in matrix form "Mat[2][3]"), but when I execute it, I obtain the following result, which does not agree with the coefficients I have introduced in the system Matrix:

CODE:

```
//Gauss Elimination
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double Mat[2][3];
    vector<double> q(2);
    int Nx = 2, ii, jj, kk;

    Mat[1][1] = 2.0;
    Mat[1][2] = 3.0;
    Mat[1][3] = 2.5;
    Mat[2][1] = 1.3;
    Mat[2][2] = 3.0;
    Mat[2][3] = 2.5;         

    cout << "Matrix: " << endl;     
    for (ii = 0; ii < Nx; ii++) {
        for (jj = 0; jj < Nx + 1; jj++) {
            cout << Mat[ii][jj] << "   ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    // Triangularization
    for (ii = 0; ii < Nx - 1; ii++)
        for (kk = ii + 1; kk < Nx; kk++)
        {
            double t = Mat[kk][ii] / Mat[ii][ii];
            for (jj = 0; jj <= Nx; jj++)
                Mat[kk][jj] = Mat[kk][jj] - t * Mat[ii][jj];
        }   // Resolution
    for (ii = Nx - 1; ii >= 0; ii--)
    {
        q[ii] = Mat[ii][Nx];
        for (jj = Nx - 1; jj > ii; jj--)                        
            q[ii] = q[ii] - Mat[ii][jj] * q[jj];
        q[ii] = q[ii] / Mat[ii][ii];
    }

    cout << "Solution of the system: " << endl;
    cout << q[1] << endl;
    cout << q[2] << endl; ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    return 0;
}
```

RESULT:

```
Matrix: 
0   2.07496e-317   6.95314e-310   
0   2   3   
Solution of the system: 
-nan
0
```

Comment: Have you looked at your post before submitting it? Does that look like formatting that will be useful for us to read? Please see [this page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question.

Comment: Please check the editor help button how to format code sections in your question properly.

Comment: Your question/problem does seem interesting, but please spend sometime formulating it better (add details of what you expected as outcomes and what you are getting instead) - also improve the readability of your question by properly formatting it - this way it may have great visual effect!

Comment: In C++, a k-element collection is indexed from 0 to k - 1.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla _"Your question/problem does seem interesting"_ Not really, it more or less falls into the _typo category_.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should **always format your code** (kind of did it for you now). Second, indexing in C and C++ starts from `0`, so the maximum allowable index is `D-1`, where `D` is the dimension. This is in contrast with e.g. MATLAB, where indexing starts from `1`. You have out of bounds access in your code, e.g. `Mat[1][3]=2.5;`, as `Mat` is declared as `double Mat[2][3];`, so the maximum row/column indexes are `1` and `2`, respectively. Same for the `q` when you display it, `q[1]` should be `q[0]` and `q[2]` should be `q[1]`. Your code will cause undefined behaviour. Compiling the code with all warnings turned on, i.e. `-Wall -Wextra` on gcc will most likely catch those kind of mistakes. Also, make sure your `for` loops don't go out of bounds as well.

As a side note, you can also directly initialize your matrix as:

```
double Mat[2][3] = { {a,b,c}, {d,e,f} }; // where a, b etc are the coefficients
```

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you read through this page. It gives a more in-depth analysis on solving linear equations with Gaussian elimination https://martin-thoma.com/solving-linear-equations-with-gaussian-elimination/

The main problem with your code is out-of-bounds access to your matrix. The index of an array's element starts at `0` which means that by having an `array[3]` your accessible elements are of index `0`, `1` and `2`.

I have hence fixed that in this edit of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

const int Nx = 2;
const int Ny = 3;
double Mat[Nx][Ny];
double q[2];

Mat[0][0] = 2.0;
Mat[0][1] = 3.0;
Mat[0][2] = 2.5;
Mat[1][0] = 1.3;
Mat[1][1] = 3.0;
Mat[1][2] = 2.5;

cout << "Matrix: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Ny; j++)
    {
        cout << Mat[i][j] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

// Triangularization
for (int i = 0; i < Nx - 1; i++)
    for (int h = i + 1; h < Nx; h++)
    {
        double t = Mat[h][i] / Mat[i][i];
        for (int j = 0; j <= Nx; j++)
        {
            Mat[h][j] = Mat[h][j] - t * Mat[i][j];
        }
    }

// Resolution
for (int i = Nx - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    q[i] = Mat[i][Nx];
    for (int j = Nx - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        q[i] = q[i] - Mat[i][j] * q[j];
    }
    q[i] = q[i] / Mat[i][i];
}

cout << "Solution of the system: " << endl;
cout << q[0] << endl;
cout << q[1] << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Using Wolfram Alpha to calculate the result of the given matrix, the result was:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRLHH.png)
And `5/6` is approximately equal to `0.8(3)` on the Y axis. I haven't managed to find the mistake in you algorithm for the X axis as it returns `-2.22045e-016`, which is either another out-of-bounds or just a mathematical error , but hopefully this will give you a start.

Comment: `-2.22045e-016` is fine, it is zero in double precision (due to round offs). Side comment: in standard C++, the dimensions of a matrix should be a compile-constant. So `int Nx = 2;` should be either `constexpr int Nx = 2;` or `const int Nx = 2;`.

Comment: Must have overlooked that while writing. Good catch.